# Vue data updates in method with setInterval() but the dom/view doesn't update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, setinterval, vue-reactivity

In my methods I have a function which is triggered using a @click in the view. 
This functions starts a timer, the timer works as I can see in the DevTools but it only updates in the DevTools when I hit refresh.

Also in the view the timer isn't shown at all as it is only rendered in once and it's not looking for updates.

UPDATED:
Full code on request

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card mt-2 p-3 w-75 mx-auto">
        <h2>League Summoners Timers</h2>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <h5>Enemy team</h5>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-2" v-for="index in lanes" :key="index">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <p class="m-0">{{ index }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div v-show="!gameStarted">
                                <div v-show="selected[index.toLowerCase()].length < 2" class="spell-image-row" v-for="spell in spells" :key="spell.name" @click="onClickSelection(spell, index)">
                                    <img class="spell-image m-1" :alt="spell.name" :src="spell.image">
                                </div>
                                <div v-show="selected[index.toLowerCase()].length >= 2">
                                    <span class="alert alert-primary">Spells selected</span>
                                    <ul class="mt-3">
                                        <li v-for="selectedSpell in selected[index.toLowerCase()]" :key="selectedSpell">
                                            {{ selectedSpell }}
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div v-show="gameStarted">
                                <div v-for="spell in selected[index.toLowerCase()]" :key="index+spell">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <img style="float: left" class="my-1" :src="spells[spell.toLowerCase()].image" :alt="spell.name" @click="onClickStartTimer(spell, index)">
                                        <p>{{ timers[index.toLowerCase()][spell.toLowerCase()] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary mr-3" @click="gameStarted = true" v-show="checkSelected() && !gameStarted">Start game</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" onClick="window.location.reload();">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "LeagueTimers",
        data() {
            return {
                gameStarted: false,
                lanes: ['Top', 'Jungle', 'Mid', 'ADC', 'Support'],
                spells: {
                    teleport: {
                        name: 'Teleport',
                        image: require('../assets/images/Teleport.png'),
                        cooldown: 420,
                    },
                    ignite: {
                        name: 'Ignite',
                        image: require('../assets/images/Ignite.png'),
                        cooldown: 180,
                    },
                    heal: {
                        name: 'Heal',
                        image: require('../assets/images/Heal.png'),
                        cooldown: 240,
                    },
                    ghost: {
                        name: 'Ghost',
                        image: require('../assets/images/Ghost.png'),
                        cooldown: 300,
                    },
                    flash: {
                        name: 'Flash',
                        image: require('../assets/images/Flash.png'),
                        cooldown: 300,
                    },
                    exhaust: {
                        name: 'Exhaust',
                        image: require('../assets/images/Exhaust.png'),
                        cooldown: 210,
                    },
                    cleanse: {
                        name: 'Cleanse',
                        image: require('../assets/images/Cleanse.png'),
                        cooldown: 210,
                    },
                    barrier: {
                        name: 'Barrier',
                        image: require('../assets/images/Barrier.png'),
                        cooldown: 180,
                    },
                    smite: {
                        name: 'Smite',
                        image: require('../assets/images/Smite.png'),
                        cooldown: 15,
                    },
                },
                selected: {
                    top: [],
                    jungle: [],
                    mid: [],
                    adc: [],
                    support: [],
                },
                timers: {
                    top: {},
                    jungle: {},
                    mid: {},
                    adc: {},
                    support: {},
                },
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onClickSelection(spell, lane) {
                this.selected[lane.toLowerCase()].push(spell.name);

            },
            onClickStartTimer(spell, lane) {
                if (!this.timers[lane.toLowerCase()][spell.toLowerCase()]) {
                    this.startTimer(spell.toLowerCase(), lane.toLowerCase(), this.spells[spell.toLowerCase()].cooldown);
                } else {
                    console.log('runt al');
                }
            },
            checkSelected() {
                for (let [key] of Object.entries(this.selected)) {
                    if (this.selected[key].length !== 2) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            },
            startTimer(spell, lane, cooldown) {
                this.timers[lane][spell] = cooldown;
                let timers = this.timers;
                setInterval(function (){
                    timers[lane][spell]--;
                    // console.log(lane+spell + " - " + timers[lane][spell]);
                    // console.log(typeof timers[lane][spell])
                    this.$forceUpdate();
                }, 1000);
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

What I've tried to far is using watch: {} and computed: {} but nothing has worked so far. I have to add that I'm pretty new to Vue.

Comment: Please post whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to declare your setInterval function this way

```
 setInterval(() => {
    this.timers[lane][spell]--;
    console.log(lane+spell + " - " + timers[lane][spell]);
    console.log(typeof timers[lane][spell])
    // this.$forceUpdate();
  }, 1000);
```

Using an arrow function, you have access to the properties data using this.timers.
Using Function syntax will create a new scope, and this.timers is not available

If you want to use the function syntax, you can bind the this object by this way

```
  setInterval(function () {
    this.timers[lane][spell]--;
    console.log(lane+spell + " - " + timers[lane][spell]);
    console.log(typeof timers[lane][spell])
  }.bind(this), 1000)
```

Also, to add reactivity to the objects inside the data property timers, you must declare them initially:

```
timers:
  { top:
    { teleport: 0,
      smite: 0, 
      ... },
    ...
   }
```

If you want to add dynamically these properties, the vue set property is the way to do it, you can read more about it here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Hi there thanks for answering! I've tried using an arrow function and applied your code. The timers still work fine, it's showing in the log and in the DevTools if I hit refresh every second. But unfortunately still not updating on the page. :(

Comment: I figure it out, the issue is, that timers object does not have timers.top.smite as an initial property, so adding the property inside the startTimer function does not make timers.top.smite reactive, and two way binding in not available. Declaring timers as: timers: { top: { teleport: 0, smite: 0, ... }, ... } does the trick. Also you can read about Vue set property here vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats, this way you can add properties dynamically. – Andres Foronda 7 mins ago    Delete

Comment: Thanks! I declared the variables and now it works. Maybe I'll to make it work with the Vue set but for now this works fine! :)

Comment: Glad to know it! Have fun, and let me play later :D